# how to protect hidden field in laravel when posting the form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, hidden

I'm working on small website using laravel 5.2  (right now add photos) and i want to update
the existing one (via popup bootstrap modal and choose the new one for the current photos , i make in the process ajax request like this )

```
   $('select#choose_update_photo').on('change',function() {

                  $category_id =  $(this).val(); // category_id for the photo

                    $.ajax({

                        type : 'post' ,

                        url: '{{ url('/ChoosePhotos') }}',
                            data : {id : $category_id ,
                            "_token": token },


                        success: function(data) { ... });
```

to the given route :

```
// the route for making post request for getting photos

    Route::post('ChoosePhotos','PhotosController@choosePhoto');
```

and this is the response :

```
public  function  choosePhoto () {


        if(request()->ajax())
        {

            $result = request()->input('id');


             $all_photos = $this->photo->RetreiveAllPhotos();
            return response()->json($all_photos) ;
        }

    }
```

and when i click on any of the  retrieves photos,,, i close the modal
and store (the retrieved (image_id) in  hidden input in my form)

like this :

but what i founded that if  i changed the hidden (id) manually  like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="pop_photo_hidden" value="20" id="hide_photo_id">
```

it will post 
that to my controller to save it ,,, and that will ruined all my work 
how to deal with that  ,,, and is there another approach for send data (in my case the photo_id) without letting the user touch them or fabricateI'm  it )

Answer (score 0):

define photo_id as guarded like this in your model.

```
protected $guarded=['photo_id'];
```